# php code to display selected row data inside textbox in codeignitter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a single form for add ,view update and delete.

My page contain table with Edit and delete link.

I need when I click on edit link then it will show the selected row data inside text box.

How can I populate the selected row data and display inside a text box?

This is all in codeIgnitter.

[plz see the attached screen shots here for refrence of my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VgDt.png)
The code is below:

**Controller**

```
public function edit()
{
    $id =  $this->input->get('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('categort_tbl');
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('category', $data);
}

public function select()
    {   
        $data['title'] = "Welcome to DB";
        $data['results'] = $this->category_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('category',$data);
    }
```

**form and list view**
**category.php**

```
<form name="frm1" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>category/save">

<table height="40px">
<tr>
<td width="9%">Category :</td>
<td width="21%"><input type="text" name="category" required=""  size="40" value=""/></td>
<td width="48%"><input type="submit" class="submit_button" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>

<div id="page-wrap">
<table width="60%" border="1">
 <tr>
    <td>Category</td> 
    <td>Date</td> 
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Actions</td>    
  </tr>
  <?php if(isset($results)){ foreach($results as $row) { ?>
 <tr>    
    <td><?php echo $row->category; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->created; ?></td>

    <td><?php echo anchor('category/edit?id='.$row->id,'Edit')?></td>

    <td><?php echo anchor('category/delete?del='.$row->id,'Delete',array('onclick' => "return confirm('Do you want delete this record')"))?></td>   


  </tr>
 <?php } } ?>

</table>
    </div>
```

Comment: So you want the category textbox to have data from the clicked row? That sounds like javascript work. Get the values from the table row and add them as inner html of the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Write query directly in controller. This is bad use of MVC. You can write your query in model file.

Your code not fetching data from database

**Controller**

```
function edit()
{
    $id =  $this->input->get('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $data['data'] = $this->model_name->get_data($id);// call your model file and pass result in data variable
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $data['title'] = "Welcome to DB";
    $data['results'] = $this->category_model->getAll();
    $this->load->view('category', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_data($id)
{
     $this->db->where('id',$id);

     $query=$this->db->get('categort_tbl');
     return $query->row();// fetch row and return from model
 }
```

**Views**

```
<tr>
<td width="9%">Category :</td>
<td width="21%"><input type="text" name="category" required=""  size="40" value="<?php echo $data->category;?>"/></td>
<td width="48%"><input type="submit" class="submit_button" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no this function is different in controller..........i use this function to load my listview from database.......bt now i need is when i click on edit link,,,this will show the selected row data in textbox............

Comment: i update my controller code......again.plz chk and help.........i also attached screen shot there......

Comment: but this shows error when i click on edit link.......Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in this line return $query->row();// fetch row and return from model.........

Comment: Ahh mu mistake IN mode use `$query=$this->db->get('categort_tbl');
         return $query->row();` I also update my answer

Comment: this will shows some warning inside textbox like..........<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'><tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan=.......Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\codeigniter_testapp\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\codeigniter_testapp\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Comment: add this t0w lines in your controller `$data['title'] = "Welcome to DB";
        $data['results'] = $this->category_model->getAll();`